# Imagem surgindo com efeito Fad-in após carregar página

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Preciso fazer 4 imagens aparecer, uma de cada vez, na minha página, após o carregamento dela.

**EFEITO NA IMAGEM:**
Seria o efeito fade-in, se não me engano é esse o nome. Esse efeito é aquele que a imagem vai surgindo do centro dela.

**CARREGAMENTO DE CADA IMAGEM**
Cada imagem, deverá aparecer após o carregamento da página, uma de cada vez, ou seja, se a primeira abre em 1 segundo a segunda abriria em 3, sendo uma diferença de 2 segundos para cada imagem.

Comment: Se você quiser uma ajuda, dicas ou orientações, ao invés de algo do tipo "façam o meu trabalho para mim", então daí pode ser que você tenha mais sorte. Poste o seu código, mesmo se estiver incompleto (preferencialmente compilável, se possível) ou mesmo que possua bugs e erros e peça ajuda. Se você tentou fazer e deu um erro que você não sabe qual é a solução, esse é o lugar certo para pedir ajuda. A única coisa que não dá é esperar que alguém faça tudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trate a animação com Javascript se a quantidade de imagens for dinâmica. Se possui um número fixo de imagens, pode criar sua animação de *fade-in* com [`@keyframes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) e fazer uso da propriedade [`animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation).

- [Como fazer animações dinâmicas com CSS3?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43144/4808)
- [Qual é a diferença entre `animation` e `transition`?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/59044/4808)

O delay entre as imagens pode ser feito com a propriedade [`animation-delay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay).

Cada imagem pode ter sua regra definida individualmente pela pseudo classe [`:ntd-child(n)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

Tendo tudo definido, será preciso usar Javascript somente para alterar o [`animation-play-state`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state) quando o documento for carregado ([nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137850/4808) há maiores informações sobre como fazer isto *cross-browser*) de `paused` para `running`. No *snippet* abaixo, aplicarei uma classe ao `body` para fazer este controle.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  document.querySelector('body')
          .classList
          .add('loaded');
});
```

```css
@keyframes fade-in {
  from { opacity: 0 }
  to   { opacity: 1 }
}

img {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fade-in 2s normal forwards ease-in-out;
  animation-play-state: paused
}

body.loaded img {
  animation-play-state: running
}

body.loaded img:nth-child(2){ animation-delay: 1s }
body.loaded img:nth-child(3){ animation-delay: 2s }
body.loaded img:nth-child(4){ animation-delay: 3s }
```

```html
<img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract/'>
<img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract/'>
<img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract/'>
<img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract/'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> $(document).ready(function(){
> 
>    setTimeout(function(){
>         $('#elementoImg1').fadeIn(1000);
>         $('#elementoImg2').fadeIn(3000);
>          $('#elementoImg3').fadeIn(5000);
>          $('#elementoImg4').fadeIn(7000);
>    }, 1000);
> 
> });
```

Comment: Também dá para usar um .delay() entre os fades, para todos terem a mesma velocidade de animação.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    
$(document).ready( function(){
      
    $('.fade').each( function(i){

    //DELAY TEMPO PARA EXECUTAR DEPOIS QUE A PAGINA CARREGA
    //ANIMATE TEMPO DE ANIMAÇÃO
    $(this).delay(2000).animate({'opacity':'1'},1500);

    }); 
      
});
```

```css
#objeto{
background-color: #ddd;
width:50%;
margin:auto;
}

.style{
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="style">
        <div class="fade">
          <h1 class="">TESTE FADEIN</h1>
          <p class="lead">TESTE FADEIN QUANDO CARREGA A PÁGINA.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```