# Como fazer com que a imagem vá surgindo aos poucos ao abrir o site? CSS TRANSIÇÃO DE IMAGEM

Tags: html, css, img, transição

boa tarde! Tudo bem?

Gostaria que quando a pessoa entrasse no site, a imagem surgisse suavemente. Estou tentando com opacity e visibility, mas não está dando certo.

Código CSS abaixo:

```
header {
   width: 1000px;
   height: auto;
   margin: 0px auto;
}

header img {
   display: block;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   visibility: hidden;
}

img {
   visibility: visible;
   transition: 2s;
}
```

Poderiam ajudar a como fazer ou alguma sugestão?

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Imagem surgindo com efeito Fad-in após carregar página](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/214119/imagem-surgindo-com-efeito-fad-in-ap%c3%b3s-carregar-p%c3%a1gina)

Comment: Tentei aqui com esse animation e loaded, mas também não deu.
Posso usar apenas CSS, sem JS.

Answer (score 0):

Neste caso você pode usar javascript e CSS, com javascript você irá adicionar uma classe CSS no body logo após a página ser carregada. Com está classe você vai setar que a imagem do header pode sair da opacidade 0 para 1

```
//Javascript
window.addEventListener('load', ()=> {
  document.body.classList.add('page-loaded')
});
```

```
//CSS
header {
   width: 1000px;
   height: auto;
   margin: 0px auto;
}

header img {
   display: block;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   opacity: 0
}

.page-loaded header img {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity 2s ease
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Da uma olhada nessa library CSS https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/
Com ela você consegue que elementos sejam carregados conforme a pagina exibe a parte da view, da pra usar delay também caso necessário